# Two ubuntu can't communicate with each other

Tags: networking

The settings is as following: (All connections are over WIFI)

0. The router is a home router from my isp, without any special configurations.
1. Lenovo ideapad 320 with Ubuntu 20.04
2. DELL Vostro laptop with Ubuntu 18.04
3. HP laptop with Windows 8

I have noticed that computers 1,2 can't communicate with each other (open a socket).

So while testing, I have observed the following:

1. 1,2,3 can ping 0.
2. 1,2 can't ping each other and can't ping 3, but they can ARP each other.
3. 3 can ping 1,2.
4. 1,2,3 can ping google.com.
5. I turned off the ufw on 1,2 and the results remains the same.

Note: When saying can or can't ping, it means that the ping is sent, but no answer is given.(Wireshark on the receiving side can't see the ping)

Additional information:
Laptop 1:

```
Laptop1 $ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp2s0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 br-0079bdd92096
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-6b43963b4800
172.19.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-dfe885633091
172.20.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-1b461c20d7f3
172.21.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-bc98c2a01fa6
172.25.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-0079bdd92096
172.26.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-f49c8ff4894d
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp2s0

Laptop1 $ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8c:16:45:12:84:ec brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a0:c5:89:b8:a8:80 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.35/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp2s0
       valid_lft 2482sec preferred_lft 2482sec
    inet6 2a00:a040:187:ec8b:a2c5:89ff:feb8:a880/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 59sec preferred_lft 29sec
    inet6 2a00:a040:187:ec8b:5ca2:5253:e9e4:6b18/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 594682sec preferred_lft 75861sec
    inet6 2a00:a040:187:ec8b:ad7e:9ad4:361:5c99/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 1138974sec preferred_lft 604783sec
    inet6 fe80::588d:2745:2389:b837/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

<more docker/vbox interfaces>
```

Laptop 2:

```
Laptop2 $ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp2s0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp2s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp2s0

Laptop2 $ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8c:47:be:49:fe:86 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:47:3d:42:a1:2f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.34/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp2s0
       valid_lft 3578sec preferred_lft 3578sec
    inet6 2a00:a040:187:ec8b:1a47:3dff:fe42:a12f/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 57sec preferred_lft 27sec
    inet6 2a00:a040:187:ec8b:2441:2a53:de1a:974c/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 601343sec preferred_lft 82884sec
    inet6 2a00:a040:187:ec8b:ba06:c010:95e6:7591/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 1138975sec preferred_lft 604784sec
    inet6 fe80::a50c:7881:4ae7:24a/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Check your wireless access point settings. Isolating wi-fi clients from each other is a common setting.

Comment: As I just updated my post (added 4th observation), I believe that something is troubling the OS from sending the ping to the LAN

Comment: Update the Question to include the complete output of `ip addr` and of `route` from both Ubuntu machines

Comment: what client are you using to connect the two computers? If the default Remmina, I am struggling to get that to work from 20.04 to 18.04 too.

Comment: At first I tried ftp (my original goal for communication) , and then I tried nc (for sanity check), and then I tried pinging from every computer to every computer

Comment: @user6035109 Check your access point settings. Client Isolation is a common setting on many access points. This denies communication between clients.

Comment: As I stated - When connecting a third Windows laptop to the LAN, it can send ping to both Ubuntu laptops and will receive a response, but the Ubuntu laptops can't receive a response for their pings to the Windows laptop. So if such setting is enforced, the Windows laptop shouldn't be able to receive ICMP response from the Ubuntu Laptops

Comment: @vidarlo Yes, I use WIFI in all communications, so no wired interface is used.

Comment: Can both of your Ubuntu systems ping the router? Can they ping the Windows laptop? Can both ping a test machine outside the LAN?

Comment: If you're trying to make a table, put it in the Question above so you can format it. Comments are intended only to help you refine and improve your question; to make it answerable.